# Akka matching Failures, and recovery

Tags: scala, akka, actor, spray

Stuff I need help with is in bold.

I have an actor that is flying multiple spray HttpRequests, the requests are paginated and the actor makes sure it writes the results in sequence into a database (sequence is important to resume crawlers). I explain this because I don't want to explore other patterns of concurrency at the moment. The actor needs to recover from timeouts without restarting.

in my actor I have the following :

```
            case f : Failure => {
                system.log.error("faiure")
                system.log.error(s"$f")
                system.shutdown()
            }
            case f : AskTimeoutException => {
                system.log.error("faiure")
                system.log.error(s"$f")
                system.shutdown()
            }
            case msg @ _ => {

                system.log.error("Unexpected message in harvest")
                system.log.error(s"${msg}")
                system.shutdown()
            }
```

**but I can't match correctly :**

```
[ERROR] [11/23/2013 14:58:10.694] [Crawler-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [ActorSystem(Crawler)] Unexpected message in harvest
[ERROR] [11/23/2013 14:58:10.694] [Crawler-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [ActorSystem(Crawler)] Failure(akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Timed out)
```

My dispatches look as follows :

```
abstract class CrawlerActor extends Actor {
  private implicit val timeout: Timeout = 20.seconds
  import context._
  def dispatchRequest(node: CNode) {
    val reqFut = (System.requester ? CrawlerRequest(node,Get(node.url))).map(r=> CrawlerResponse(node,r.asInstanceOf[HttpResponse]))
    reqFut pipeTo self
  }


class CrawlerRequester extends Actor  {
  import context._
  val throttler = context.actorOf(Props(classOf[TimerBasedThrottler],System.Config.request_rate),"throttler")
  throttler ! SetTarget(Some(IO(Http).actorRef))

  def receive : Receive = {
    case CrawlerRequest(type_,request) => {
      throttler forward request
    }
  }
}
```

**Once I find the correct way of matching, is there anyway I can get my hands on the CrawlerRequest that the timeout occurred with ? it contains some state I need to figure out how to recover.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to type out the full path of the Failure case class, (or import it I guess).

```
case f: akka.actor.Status.Failure => {
                system.log.error("faiure")
                system.log.error(s"${f.cause}")
                system.shutdown()
            }
```

That just leaves getting to the request associated with the timeout. Seems a map and pipe with a custom failure handler is needed at point request dispatch. Looking into it now.

The following trampolines the timeout into the actor.

```
case class CrawlerRequestTimeout(request: CrawlerRequest)
abstract class CrawlerActor extends Actor {
  private implicit val timeout: Timeout = 20.seconds
  import context._
  def dispatchRequest(node: CNode) {
    val req =  CrawlerRequest(node,Get(node.url))
    val reqFut = (System.requester ? req).map(r=> CrawlerResponse(node,r.asInstanceOf[HttpResponse]))

    reqFut onFailure {
        case te: akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException => self ! CrawlerRequestTimeout(req)
    }
    reqFut pipeTo self
  }
}
```

with a match of :

```
 case timeout : CrawlerRequestTimeout => {
                println("boom")
                system.shutdown()
            }
```

Need to find a way of suppressing the exception though, it's still firing. Perhaps suppression isn't really a concern, verifying.

No, suppression is a concern, or the exception trickles down to the msg @ _, need to put in  a case class to absorb the redundant failure message.

ok, so getting rid of the pipeto gets rid of the exception entering the client actor. It's also a lot easier to read :D

```
abstract class CrawlerActor extends Actor {
  private implicit val timeout: Timeout = 20.seconds
  import context._
  def dispatchRequest(node: CNode) {
    val req =  CrawlerRequest(node,Get(node.url))
    val reqFut = (System.requester ? req)

    reqFut onFailure {
        case te: akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException => self ! CrawlerRequestTimeout(req)
    }
    reqFut onSuccess {
        case r: HttpResponse => self ! CrawlerResponse(node,r)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This situation occurs if you use `pipeTo` to respond to message that sent by `tell`.

For example:

```
in actorA: actorB ! message
in actorB: message => doStuff pipeTo sender
in actorA: receives not 'scala.util.Failure', but 'akka.actor.Status.Failure'
```

The additional logic in `pipeTo` is to transform `Try`'s `Failure` into akka's actor `Failure` (`akka.actor.Status.Failure`). This works fine when you use `ask` pattern, because temporary ask actor handle `akka.actor.Status.Failure` for you, but does not work well with `tell`.

Hope this short answer helps :)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you currently don't succeed in matching the `AskTimeoutException`.

If so, you should match `case Failure(AskTimeoutException) => ...` instead of `case f : AskTimeoutException => ...`.